# Speeding up SQL Query with CASE in JOIN

Tags: excel, vba, db2, db2-400

working on a DB2 database using SQL in VBA to make some custom reports. I came up with the below query, but it took like 45-minutes to run with 80,000 results... the table BILLPRC probably has twice that in total before the WHERE clause. Just wondering if there is a better way to write the query to speed it up. This might be a pretty ambiguous question, so I can explain further if you need more info.

```
SELECT b.BLCO# || RIGHT('00000' || b.BLACCT, 5) Acct, b.BLRECT Type, b.BLREC# Record, i.INAME || ' ' ||       i.INAME2 Desc, b.BLPPGM# Promo, SUBSTR(b.BLPEFFD, 4, 2) || SUBSTR(b.BLPEFFD, 6, 2) || SUBSTR(b.BLPEFFD, 2, 2)     Eff, SUBSTR(b.BLPENDD, 4, 2) || SUBSTR(b.BLPENDD, 6, 2) || SUBSTR(b.BLPENDD, 2, 2) Exp, CASE   
    WHEN (p.PPPRC1 = '0') THEN (p.PPPRC2)   
    WHEN (p.PPPRC1 != '0') THEN (p.PPPRC1) END Price,   
  CASE   
    WHEN (p.PPPRC1 = '0') THEN (p.PPCST2)   
    WHEN (p.PPPRC1 != '0') THEN (p.PPCST1) END Allow, i.ILASTC Cost   
FROM QS36F.BILLPRC b   
LEFT JOIN QS36F.PROMO p   
  ON b.BLREC# || b.BLPPGM# = p.PPREC || p.PPPGM#   
LEFT JOIN QS36F.ITEM i   
  ON CASE   
    WHEN (b.BLRECT = 'I') AND (b.BLREC# = i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT) THEN 1   
    WHEN (b.BLRECT = 'P') AND (b.BLREC# = i.IPRCCD) THEN 1   
    END = 1   
WHERE (b.BLPPGM# != '') AND (b.BLSTS != 'H')   
ORDER BY (b.BLACCT)
```

I have a feeling there isn't given the amount of records and CASEs being checked.

Comment: Can you use an indexed view?

Comment: Best first thing to do might be to move the files out of QS36F and create actual relational tables. The System/36 environment isn't really appropriate for high-performing SQL (maybe not even for medium-performing). Take a good close look at the actual file definitions.

Comment: Stuff like `b.BLREC# || b.BLPPGM# = p.PPREC || p.PPPGM#` means you have a multi-part key, which violates good normalization practices.  It also means you can't use indices, so the query will be slow.  Can you just compare columns against each other?  Your `SELECT CASE` doesn't explicitly list the case when `p` is `null`.  DB2 has utilities to convert CYMD dates to other formats.  Your `ON CASE` works out to be an `OR` condition, which will help some.

Comment: Access paths [indices] can be used, they just need to be matching expression and matching typed derived-key AccPth, and querying on a release\TR-level of the system where the SQL Query Engine enables [join] implementations using such derived keys. The missing ELSE on the CASE expression means when P IS NULL, the effect is the NULL value.  I would not be surprised if `ON b.BLRECT IN ('I', 'P') AND ( (b.BLRECT = 'I' AND b.BLREC# = i.IMFGR || i.ICOLOR || i.IPATT) OR (b.BLRECT = 'P' AND b.BLREC# = i.IPRCCD) )` was able to be optimized better than the `ON CASE ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may likely get better performance by changing your WHERE predicate `(b.BLPPGM# != '') AND (b.BLSTS != 'H')` by rewriting it in the join condition(s).

Try not to concatenate your fields used for joining, if possible.  For example, instead of

```
  LEFT JOIN QS36F.PROMO p   
     ON  b.BLREC# || b.BLPPGM# = p.PPREC || p.PPPGM#
```

you could say

```
  LEFT JOIN QS36F.PROMO p   
    ON  b.BLREC#  = p.PPREC
    and b.BLPPGM# = p.PPPGM#
```

or equivalently

```
  LEFT JOIN QS36F.PROMO p   
     ON (b.BLREC#, b.BLPPGM#) = (p.PPREC, p.PPPGM#)
```

adding in the logic from your WHERE clause

```
  LEFT JOIN QS36F.PROMO p   
     ON (b.BLREC#, b.BLPPGM#) = (p.PPREC, p.PPPGM#)
```

Of course, this assumes that the corresponding fields are the same type, or compatible types, and ideally the fields will be the same size. DB2 can often automatically convert one type to another compatible type.  String types are often compatible with each other, and numeric types often with each other.

Then, most importantly, make sure you have the right indexes available.  (I'm not too familiar with the S/36 mode environment, but I'm assuming you can create indexes over it.)  Indexes can also be built over a derived column, ie. an expression such as concatenation.

Comment: Concatenation in the JOIN means that the optimiser has no index it can choose, which can slow performance.  The advice for indexes (which has been given several times) is the typical way to reduce SQL run times.

Comment: The files are conspicuously externally-described, so even if linked or previously were described by a file definition of IDDU Data Dictionary (DTADCT), that legacy fact is of no consequence to the scenario [except if there is bad decimal data]. The location, either by library name [QS36F] or the operational environment\mode [S/36EE] does not restrict indexing; a [derived] keyed access path can be created, irrespective of mode and in which library. A derived-key AccPth that includes the identical concatenation should be eligible to implement a join.

Answer (score 1):

For reporting purposes, use a [materialized query table](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509melnyk/), unless if you can't really afford the CPU time. I know it's a bit lazy, but MQTs are meant for when you are okay with getting for instance hourly updated results, and don't want to start normalizing and optimizing your database. You have a working logic, and you apparently understand it, so go with it.

Comment: In what way do you suggest would an MQT be easked or more efficient in a case like this?   The article you reference is for DB2 LUW, and is not always accurate for DB2 for i. This question is for DB2 running on IBM i, which has somewhat different features than DB2 LUW.  For example, MQT's must be `MAINTAINED BY USER`, so there is no automatic refresh by the system.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's DB2 for i....you might want to tag it appropriately

Assuming it is, have you used the "Run & Explain" option in iNav's Run SQL scripts to see if the DB recommends any new indexes?